# iOS: App Not Appearing In Notification Center In Settings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, notifications, settings

I have an app that allows sends the user an alert through the notification center when an event date is approaching. But, when I run the app on my device, I go to the "Notifications" tab in the Settings, and my application doesn't appear in there. I also added this code in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in the App Delegate at the bottom, and I thought it would do the trick:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

I'm aware that the code is usually only used for push notifications, but apparently this code prompts the user asking them if they would like to turn notifications on, rather than installing the app with them off by default.

Is there any other code that I should be adding to make it appear in the Notifications tab in the Settings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the development portal, make sure that push notifications is configured for your App ID. Once that's configured, you'll need to download and install the modified profile.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted your answer, cannot roll that back. 

Will leave my comment and question as well then. 
Major part of app users (app is released) can find app in Notifications Center, but only some users are not able to find it there, and as a result, are not receiving any pushes.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you actually can register for remote notifications - in app delegate you should implement 2 methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
```

If the second one is called, something gone bad.
Check your profiles and read [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/)